# HTML Form and Table Code Works in Fiddle But not on Site

Tags: html, forms, html-table, jsfiddle

I have a page that has several tables that also are forms that send data to a PHP script. You can see the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/1gL4qzh2/

```
<form action='singleview.php' method='post'>
<table id='scholarship' style='float:left;' align='center'>
  <thead>
    <th class='head' colspan='3' style='text-align:center;'>University of Michigan--Dearborn
      <br>
      <br>Full Tuition
      <br>
      <br>Public
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type='hidden' name='id' value='ARLUJ'>
      <input type='submit' value='View More Details'>
    </th>
  </thead>
  </form>
  </table>
```

The issue I am having is that the first two table on the top left corner the button "View More Details" is not working. All of the other tables they work fine on. When I put it in a fiddle they seem to work properly.

Does anyone know what is in the fiddle code that I am missing for these to work?

Comment: Please dont use `<br />` for extra rows in a table, just make new rows. Also for the HTML to be valid, you have to add the slash at the end of the `br` and of the `input`s

Comment: the fiddle seems to be working for me, so can you explain what's not working for you? Also, I'd reconsider the design of the site. You seem to be using POST requests for what are really just GETs that could be done with a very simple link button.

Comment: Please don't use tables to make simple boxes. Use divs (or sections, or articles, or whatever has the right semantics). Use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) as you have markup errors that one would delete.

Comment: @Marv — "Also for the HTML to be valid, you have to add the slash" — You're thinking of XHTML. That slash isn't required in HTML (and is only allowed there in HTML 5 because of the number of people addicted to XML).